# Unable to use systemctl

Tags: 16.04, systemd

```
user@node15:~$ systemctl
Failed to list units: No such method 'ListUnitsFiltered'
user@node15:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure systemd
[sudo] password for user: 
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Operation failed: No such file or directory
user@node15:~$
```

This is what I get from a machine running ubuntu Server 16.04-2. I've seen errors like this before, usually a restart fixes it, but this time it didn't work. How do I find the cause and fix it?

Comment: Please run `service --status-all` does this run, if so then what did you do before this situation.

Comment: https://ptpb.pw/cEMQ. The above command does run. I don't understand the second part of the question, can you clarify?

Comment: I am asking was there anything you did prior to the `systemctl` not working, perhaps an update or so?

Comment: @George: I'm don't have the information, this was the state the machine was handed down to me, sorry. :(

Comment: Then you need to ask whoever gave what they did as something was definitely done to affect the systemd program

Comment: Less likely to figure that one out, any other ways to debug and fix without reinstalling, or need I go for a reinstall to fix it?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd `

Comment: Perhaps the previous administrator reverted the system's init system to `upstart`? Please check if the package `upstart-sysv` is installed (e.g. `apt-cache policy upstart-sysv`).

Comment: Upstart is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments helped figure it out. Upstart was enabled instead of systemd, followed steps mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) to revert it back.

```
apt-get install systemd-sysv ubuntu-standard
```

Comment: This works but as per [George's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925932/unable-to-use-systemctl#comment1463860_925932), the `--reinstall` option is needed if the packages are already installed (and up to date).

Comment: Don't forget to reboot the system